# Display message like the mute/volume transparent rectangle on iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, view

Does anyone know how to use the semi-transparent rectangle to display info to the user on the iPhone SDK? I mean the one that is used when you mute the phone or press the volume up/down keys.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are many drop in classes out there for you to choose from.

[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Also, check out [TapkuLibrary](http://tapku.com/) also has a nice progress hud class.

Comment: Aren't there any built-in options for this? I'm not really sure I wanna use external libraries.